# Google Play Test: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This task listener doesn't support child surface attachment

Tags: android, google-play

There is a bug reported from by Google Play store testing (Pre launch Report) on 1 device.

Generic Small Desktop (x86) -(virtual)1366x768Android 12L (SDK 32)-x86_64en_ZA.

I am not sure what is the issue here. Need help in understanding what it means and what can be done to resolve it.

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: This task listener doesn't support child surface attachment.
  at com.android.wm.shell.ShellTaskOrganizer$TaskListener.attachChildSurfaceToTask (ShellTaskOrganizer.java:108)
  at com.android.wm.shell.compatui.CompatUIWindowManager.attachToParentSurface (CompatUIWindowManager.java:190)
  at com.android.wm.shell.compatui.CompatUIWindowManager.attachToParentSurface (CompatUIWindowManager.java:110)
  at android.view.WindowlessWindowManager.addToDisplay (WindowlessWindowManager.java:146)
  at android.view.WindowlessWindowManager.addToDisplayAsUser (WindowlessWindowManager.java:187)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:1149)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:1026)
  at android.view.SurfaceControlViewHost.setView (SurfaceControlViewHost.java:264)
  at com.android.wm.shell.compatui.CompatUIWindowManager.initCompatUi (CompatUIWindowManager.java:288)
  at com.android.wm.shell.compatui.CompatUIWindowManager.createLayout (CompatUIWindowManager.java:122)
  at com.android.wm.shell.compatui.CompatUIController.createLayout (CompatUIController.java:229)
  at com.android.wm.shell.compatui.CompatUIController.onCompatInfoChanged (CompatUIController.java:141)
  at com.android.wm.shell.ShellTaskOrganizer.notifyCompatUI (ShellTaskOrganizer.java:645)
  at com.android.wm.shell.ShellTaskOrganizer.onTaskInfoChanged (ShellTaskOrganizer.java:466)
  at android.window.TaskOrganizer$1.lambda$onTaskInfoChanged$6$TaskOrganizer$1 (TaskOrganizer.java:283)
  at android.window.TaskOrganizer$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:67)
```

I have tried testing it in multiple devices locally but am unable t reproduce the issue.

Comment: post your question on the google community as well. I looked all over the internet for a fix but didn't found any. 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/community?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Here is away to reproduce it:

[image]

[image]

[Source](https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/android-native-crash-problem-creator-3-7-2/58828/4)

Now you can debug it and fix it. Also you can ignore it if you do not support desktops.